# Exporting images to my Google Earth Engine repository

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, export, repository

So I understand that you have repositories in Google Earth Engine where the scripts are stored. I would also like to add images to a repository, particularly in a folder as seen below. I thought that Export.image.toAsset would do it, but this seems to store the image completely separate from the repository and therefore cannot be cloned in a repository.

[image: s]

Answer (score 1):

The folder in your image is under the 'Scripts' section, that folder can only store your EE scripts/source code. Imagery is under the 'Assets' section. There you can create a folder and use Export.image.toAsset (providing the assetId 'users/yourUsername/images/theNameOfTheImageYouAreExporting').